# Change Bootstrap's carousel arrow color when slide changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got this working for a single carousel. However, when there's more than 1 carousel, it doesn't work.

Could some help? It works only when one carousel is added.

**JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/177eLsmh/**

HTML

```
<span class="pull-right">
    <a class="" href="#TeamCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="controls class-fade"> << </i></a> 
                 &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a class="" href="#TeamCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="controls class-active"> >> </i></a>
</span>

<hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="carousel slide"  data-interval="false" data-wrap="false" id="TeamCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide1 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide2 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide3 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide4 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide5 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide6 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide7 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide8 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<span class="pull-right">
    <a class="" href="#Team1Carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="controls class-fade"> << </i></a> 
                 &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a class="" href="#Team1Carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="controls class-active"> >> </i></a>
</span>

<hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="carousel slide"  data-interval="false" data-wrap="false" id="Team1Carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide1 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide2 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide3 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide4 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide5 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide6 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide7 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide8 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.class-fade {
  color: grey;
}
.class-active {
  color: red;
}
```

JS

```
$('#TeamCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
var inner = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');

var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
  if (e.direction === 'left') {
        controls[0].className = 'controls class-active';
  }
  if (e.direction === 'right') {
        controls[1].className = 'controls class-active'
  }

  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.lastElementChild) {
    controls[1].className = 'controls class-fade'
  }
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.firstElementChild) {
    controls[0].className = 'controls class-fade'
  }
})
$('#Team1Carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
var inner = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');

var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
  if (e.direction === 'left') {
        controls[0].className = 'controls class-active';
  }
  if (e.direction === 'right') {
        controls[1].className = 'controls class-active'
  }

  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.lastElementChild) {
    controls[1].className = 'controls class-fade'
  }
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.firstElementChild) {
    controls[0].className = 'controls class-fade'
  }
})
```

Comment: In JSFiddle it works fine. What is your trouble?

Comment: You were using same class for both carousel that was causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below solution. You were using same class for both carousel that was causing this issue.

```js
$('#TeamCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
var inner = document.querySelector('#first-carousel-inner');

var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.first_carousel');
  if (e.direction === 'left') {
  controls[0].className = 'first_carousel class-active';
  }
  if (e.direction === 'right') {
  controls[1].className = 'first_carousel class-active'
  }
  
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.lastElementChild) {
    controls[1].className = 'first_carousel class-fade'
  }
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.firstElementChild) {
    controls[0].className = 'first_carousel class-fade'
  }
})
$('#Team1Carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
var inner = document.querySelector('#second-carousel-inner');

var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.second_carousel');
  if (e.direction === 'left') {
  controls[0].className = 'second_carousel class-active';
  }
  if (e.direction === 'right') {
  controls[1].className = 'second_carousel class-active'
  }
  
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.lastElementChild) {
    controls[1].className = 'second_carousel class-fade'
  }
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.firstElementChild) {
    controls[0].className = 'second_carousel class-fade'
  }
})
```

```css
.class-fade {
  color: grey;
}
.class-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<span class="pull-right">
    <a class="" href="#TeamCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="controls class-fade first_carousel"> << </i></a> 
           &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a class="" href="#TeamCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="controls class-active first_carousel"> >> </i></a>
</span>

<hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="carousel slide"  data-interval="false" data-wrap="false" id="TeamCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" id="first-carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide1 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide2 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide3 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide4 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide5 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide6 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide7 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide8 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<span class="pull-right">
    <a class="" href="#Team1Carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="controls class-fade second_carousel"> << </i></a> 
           &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a class="" href="#Team1Carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="controls class-active second_carousel"> >> </i></a>
</span>

<hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="carousel slide"  data-interval="false" data-wrap="false" id="Team1Carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" id="second-carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide1 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide2 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide3 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide4 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide5 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide6 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide7 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Slide8 goes here 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ElaineByene Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

In your second carousel `on slide` function you need to edit the index value you are using to access the `controls` array, as there are 4 controls in the array. You also need to make sure you're targeting the correct `'.carousel-inner'` so that `.lastElementChild` and `.firstElementChild` are working properly

```
$('#Team1Carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
console.log(e.relatedTarget);
var inner = document.querySelector('#Team1Carousel .carousel-inner');

var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
  if (e.direction === 'left') {
        controls[2].className = 'controls class-active'; //changed from controls[0].className
  }
  if (e.direction === 'right') {
        controls[3].className = 'controls class-active' //changed from controls[1].className
  }

  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.lastElementChild) {
    controls[3].className = 'controls class-fade' //changed from controls[1].className
  }
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.firstElementChild) {
    controls[2].className = 'controls class-fade'//changed from controls[0].className
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `<i class="controls class-fade"> &lt;&lt; </i>` to `<i class="controls class-active"> &lt;&lt; </i>`